# Parameter in $stateParams are undefined in resolve

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have a page showing a list of contact and clicking on one of the contacts in the view should switch to detail state as below:

dashboard-contacts-controller.js

```
vm.viewContact = function(contactId) {
  console.log("Load contact " + contactId);
  $state.go("app.dashboards_contact", {"id": contactId});
}
```

contacts-module.js

```
.state('app.dashboards_contact', {
      url: '/dashboard-contact/:id',
      views: {
        'content@app': {
          templateUrl: 'app/main/apps/dashboards/contacts/about/about.html',
          controller: 'DashboardContactController as vm'
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        contact: ['DashboardContactsDataService', function($stateParams, DashboardContactsDataService) {
            console.log($stateParams.id);
            return DashboardContactsDataService.get($stateParams.id);
          }
        ]
      },
      bodyClass: 'dashboard-contact'
    });
```

$stateParams.id in resolve is always undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt inject $stateParams in resolve. Shouldn't it be

```
resolve: {
    contact: ['$stateParams', DashboardContactsDataService', function($stateParams, DashboardContactsDataService) {
        console.log($stateParams.id);
        return DashboardContactsDataService.get($stateParams.id);
    }
    ]
},
```